# Getting Error Unexpected null value when clicked on onTap function of Inkwell

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-image-picker

I am getting following null value error when I try to click on Inkwell.
I don't know where I am getting the error and I am not able to fix this issue. I tried many things but nothing works.
Error:

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown while handling a gesture:
Unexpected null value.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49           throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 855:63       nullCheck
packages/get/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart 36:39                        ExtensionBottomSheet.bottomSheet
packages/agriplus/Registration%20Screens/Signup%2520Screens/signup_screen_5.dart 48:9  imagePickerOption
packages/flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart 1154:21                                    handleTap
packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 275:24                                   invokeCallback
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 654:11                                          handleTapUp
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 311:5                                           [_checkUp]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 244:7                                           handlePrimaryPointer
packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 630:9                                    handleEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 98:12                                [_dispatch]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 143:9                                <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart 21:13               forEach
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 141:17                               [_dispatchEventToRoutes]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 127:7                                route
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 488:19                                      handleEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 468:14                                      dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 333:11                                     dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 413:7                                       [_handlePointerEventImmediately]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 376:5                                       handlePointerEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 323:7                                       [_flushPointerEventQueue]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 292:9                                       [_handlePointerDataPacket]
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1319:13                                    invoke1
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 303:5                                      invokeOnPointerDataPacket
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 168:39                                         [_onPointerData]
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 791:20                                         <fn>
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 720:14                                         <fn>
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 317:16                                         loggedHandler
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 574:37       _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 579:39       dcall
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#c150a
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(320.8, 411.0)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(20.8, 15.1)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
====================================================================================================
```

Relevant Part of code:
This are the function I created above:

```
  File? pickedImage;

  void imagePickerOption() {
    Get.bottomSheet(
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            height: 250,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "Select Image From",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      pickImage(
                        ImageSource.camera,
                      );
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.camera,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    label: const Text(
                      "CAMERA",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      pickImage(
                        ImageSource.gallery,
                      );
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.image,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    label: const Text(
                      "GALLERY",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Get.back();
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    label: const Text(
                      "CANCEL",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void pickImage(ImageSource imageType) async {
    try {
      final photo = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: imageType);
      if (photo == null) return;
      final tempImage = File(photo.path);
      setState(() {
        pickedImage = tempImage;
      });
      Get.back();
    } catch (error) {
      debugPrint(error.toString());
    }
  }
```

When I click on Edit Icon (InkWell) I got error:

```
Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 120,
                    height: 120,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 4,
                        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          spreadRadius: 2,
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                          offset: const Offset(0, 10),
                        )
                      ],
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    child: ClipOval(
                      child: Image.network(
                        profilePicture,
                        width: 120,
                        height: 120,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: imagePickerOption,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 40,
                        width: 40,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          border: Border.all(
                            width: 4,
                            color:
                                Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                          ),
                          color: const Color(0XFF00B251),
                        ),
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.edit_outlined,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: Are you using `MaterialApp` or `GetMaterialApp`?

Comment: MaterialApp, Should I use GetMaterialApp? or Can I do it without Get Package?

Comment: Explained in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get.bottomSheet` is treated as a route and needs `BuildContext` to be pushed onto the stack by `Navigator`. Unlike `showModalBottomSheet` where context must be provided as an argument, Get provides the context by `GetMaterialApp`.

**Example** native Material

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => const FlutterLogo(size: 400),
);
```

**Solution** to `Get.bottomSheet` context null error of get: ^4.6.6 library at line 36 of extension_navigation.dart

```dart
// Change
MaterialApp()
// to
GetMaterialApp()
```